# Manipulating field content on client / server using autoform for meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am playing around with Meteor and autoform.

### My setup

I have an input field (type "time") as part of my schema for the collection of "Songs" that forces the user to type the syntax *[num][num]:[num][num]*.
This is my schema:

```js
time: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Time",
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
        afFieldInput: {
            type: 'time'
        }
    }
}
```

### What I want to do

After hitting "submit" but **before validation** I want to **convert the string** (e.g. "03:45") **to seconds (Number)** so that the validation passes without an error.

Also: when reading the data from the db I want to **convert it back to a string**, so that it fits in the input field as a value.

I could not find the answer in the docs for autoform, collection2 or simple-schema (or at least did not understand it ;-)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I managed to convert the string to seconds by defining a `autoValue: function() {}`in the Sings schema. I did not try the way back from the db to the form yet. Another thing is, that **I need the ID of the album** as an attribute for the song-doc. Without autoform I had passed it from the template helper as an parameter to the `Meteor.call()`, but with autoform I don't know the best way to do it. Maybe via hidden input field? Or any more fancy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use autoform hooks. The information that you are looking for is here:
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks

More specifically what you are looking for is this:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  someFormId: {
    formToDoc: function(doc) {
        // Called every time an insert or typeless form
        // is revalidated, which can be often if keyup
        // validation is used.
    },
    docToForm: function(doc, ss) {
        // Called whenever `doc` attribute reactively changes, before values
        // are set in the form fields.
    }
});
```

The doc can be modified in each hook specifically when it is going to the collection and when it is being reactively pulled from the collection.

Comment: Great, thanks! Can it be that the hooks are only available on the client? What if I wanted to do sth. exclusively on the server? I tried to call `AutoForm.hooks` on the server and `AutoForm` was not defined there. And am I right that the only way to hook in on the server side is to pass a `meteormethod="someMeteorMethod"` in the HTML Template and then do the magic there?

Comment: hooks are only available on the client given that autoform itself is a client only package. Any validation and clean up should be done in your schema and not inside the hooks given that schema is called both on client and on server side